# ios App creating a local file on mac

Tags: ios, iphone, file

Helle guys,

Form this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) , we know that each app is an island, which means that an app is generally prohibited from accessing or creating files outside its containers. but also the page says One exception to this rule occurs when an app uses public system interfaces to access things such as the user’s contacts or music. In those cases, the system frameworks handle any file-related operations needed to read from or modify the appropriate data stores. Can any one presents an example of using public system interfaces in codes to edit a simple contacts seem like "Hello world" in txt is not possible  or point me to a page has such example? Thank you.

Comment: This depends on what kind of file you need to handle

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff   What kind of files do you have experience with? "Hello World" in txt seems like impossible, which means we need to edit contacts or music.

Answer (score 0):

There are some like:

- [Assets Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html) to access the user media.
- [iPod Library Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to acces the users music.
- [Address Book Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) for accessing users contact
- [EventKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/) for the calendar.

Theses some of the most used once, there is not API that will allow an iOS app to create a local file on your mac. You will need to build to apps for this, one for iOS and one for the OSX. These two apps should then communicate with each other to so that the OSX app can create the file.

An other option is to use iCloud with [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html)